# "Random" key generated every second, how can I tell how it is created?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, reverse-engineering

Long story short, I have a program that generates 32 character keys. These keys change every second so I assume they are time based. Some of these keys are as follows:

- `8é03]TyjzyQ;µ°g'Ôñ"KL2ûä*ª`
- `ÁÁÚô£÷=ÁËè«-w¢c££ià(tóWìQÁ`
- `œÃ¶~çY»BõÙ)ýŒdÒŒDîýWH (œI`
- `.ë[VÒ;S÷:uYªaCXZÃ.0Þ¯ó{œü
  X·ú`

These keys go together with another parameter called `serialNumber`. The program, after generating a key like above, forms (with serialNumber and key) a 52 character base32 string called `secret`. I do not know how to relate the keys to the exact second they were created (maybe unix time stamp encryption?) but I have a `secret` value, and a `serialNumber`, and my goal is to reverse engineer the key from it. Given this is possible, can someone lead me down the right path? I'm told I have enough information to actually get the `key` from the `secret` and `serialNumber` I just don't know how to decrypt my `secret` (looks something like `TQCN562J5NUVFWMNCMHFJLXHWU4R2T7MAC4NFHMFGJD4NNTYWW7A`) with my `serialNumber` (looks something like `49284393`). Any advice would be appreciated.

BTW this is extra credit work, I don't care about the points just want to learn how to solve this problem. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: How are the keys output? Are you given the binary that generates the keys? If so, why don't you just disassemble the program to find out the key?

If you know that the problem is solvable without disassembling the program, what did you cover in class recently? (I'm assuming this was assigned as part of a class since you said that it's extra credit work.)

Comment: @WillS Yes I am given the binary executable that generates secrets. If I try and create a secret without giving it a key to build it with, it will generate a key to build the secret with, then output both the secret and the key. The `key` it auto-generates though is different every second you run the program. Assuming I disassemble it, could I find how it creates a secret from a given `key` and `serialNumber`?

Comment: @WillS BTW running `objdump -Mintel -d ./keygen` gives me a file with 270,000 lines in it. Not sure if this is crazy or not but seems nearly impossible to sift through haha

Comment: @BradWerth Yes it was..I deleted my previous question so that this is the only version of it